# Updating State with strange behaviour

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and was wondering if someone could try to explain this behaviour to me.
I implemented with intention to setState to a value of 1. I thoguth this has to break the code, but somehow instead my state gets magically set to 0 after all.

```
    state = {
        counters: [
            { id: 1, value: 0 },
            { id: 2, value: 4 },
            { id: 3, value: 3 },
            { id: 4, value: 2 },
        ],
    };

...

    handleReset = () => {
        const counters = this.state.counters.map(
            (c) => (c.value = 0),
        );
        this.setState({
            value: 1,
        });
    };
...

     <button
         onClick={this.handleReset}
         className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
     >
         Reset
     </button>
```

See the full code at:
https://github.com/kkroeger93/counter-app/blob/main/src/components/Counters.js

Comment: Why don't you have a constructor in your class component?

Comment: I learned it this way. There are two ways to initiate the state.
I also read this: 
[Alternative Class Component Syntax](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/react-alternative-class-component-syntax)

Comment: `The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted. When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise, this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to bugs.` -> from React docs. Counter.js in the link shared uses props but doesn't have a constructor. It is good practise to add your state and initialize props in the construtor.

Comment: If the approach you've learned and are using is because it lets you write fewer lines of code, it would be better to implement a functional component with hooks over a class component. But, that's just my opinion. Your call at the end of the day.

Comment: Thank you, this is good to know. I'll try to update my flow :)

Answer (score 0):

In `handleReset`, you are using `this.state.counters` map where inner objects of component state are getting updated to `zero`

```
handleReset = () => {
        const counters = this.state.counters.map(
            (c) => (c.value = 0),
        );
        this.setState({
            value: 1,
        });
    };
```

change like this,

```
   handleReset = () => {
        const counters = this.state.counters.map(
            (c) => {
                return { ...c, value: 1 }
            }
        );
        this.setState({
            counters
        });
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining, but I already know how to fix the issue, but Im not 100% aware why its not crashing. Could it be, that if I call setState() with incorrect values, that the default fallback is to update the whole state to current state ? And because I'm referring to the counters object by reference, the counters object of the "newly maped" object gets kicked into the state ?

Comment: Even though `counters.map` created a new array with a new reference. Internal objects of the counters array have the same reference that's the reason when you update the inner object of the state it's updating the current state tooo. The reason it's reflecting in the browser is due to `this.setState({ value: 1});`. Even though react state not updated using setState still object of the state is updated which reflect in render later. @K.Kröger